# crystal report crosstab report:remove summary for single entry

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crosstab

I have developed a cross-tab report based on product and amount and have added groups on principal name.

The problem is, when I apply summary option for each group, it also displays, a sub total field for an entry where there's only one entry[here in case of principal a]...how do i remove it

```
                         2009          2010                   2011
             principal product qty    product qty           product qty
                a       a1     10       a1    11                a1   12
                     total     10             11                     12

                b       a1     10       a1    10                a1   10
                        a2     20       a2    20                a2   20
                     total     30             30                     30                                          
                        b1     10       b1    10                b1   10
                        b2     20       b2    20                b2   20
                     total     30             30                     30
```

Answer (score 3):

You can hide by right click on cross-tab expert and go to last tab.

Tick on  "Suppress Row Grand Totals", and then check preview. 
There is other option for column total ,row total to suppress.

Even you can set particular field grand total by select that part in graphical presentation of cross-tab in above mention option. So Then , you can get option too.

http://scn.sap.com/thread/3324003

http://scn.sap.com/thread/973572

http://www.forumtopics.org/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=856546

Comment: thanks for the reply...

I've had suppressed the fields previously,what i exactly want is 'conditional formatting'..i.e. it will display the sub-total for multiple entry and suppress where row entry=1

Comment: if  you are able then paste your image also explain or draw your issue.

Comment: i've thought about making sub reports...although it will solve the problem but that'll increase overhead only.also tried the gridrow column index and grid row column value...with nothing happening...i find this other guy was also looking for the same problem here,referencing his image links for better understanding..

what i have...

http://i.stack.imgur.com/fpAQa.png

what i need...

http://i.stack.imgur.com/NYxgE.png

all i need is to remove the sub group totals where entry=1